# Draw small blue square when over my icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

how to draw a small blue square on the overview of my icon for my mouse like this

[image: Before]

[image: after]

Comment: Is this supposed to happpen when you hover over the image?

Comment: Could you clarify for us whether you require this to be done in javascript, or whether a pure CSS solution would be acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS is by far easier, though I'm not even 100% sure the route you're looking for since the question is vague and the tags are plentiful.

That being said, give this a whirl:

```
img:hover { border: 5px solid blue; }
```

And the obligatory demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xCU74/

Comment: Does IE support this by now? Afaik older versions didn't support hover other than anchor elements.

Comment: @Brad a hover selector wont work in all browsers unless its an anchor tag

Comment: @Shadow: To my knowledge, you just need to keep it properly formatted with the DOCTYPE for it to work (though I may be wrong).

Comment: IE6 and lower only supports `:hover` on links.

Comment: Stylistically, should we prefer `border` to separate `border-style`, `border-width`, and `border-color`, or vice versa? Do they work differently in the presence of overriding rules?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). Given the `javascript` tag in the question, I see this as a viable option, while still maintaining as light-weight an approach as possible.

Comment: @Tom: border is short-hand for the others. I tend to use the short-hands just to keep the file shorter, but it's entirely up to you. You could use something like `border: 1px solid black;` then come back and use `border-color: blue;` and not override width or style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a CSS-only solution, this will work:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    img.hoverborder {
        border: solid 3px transparent;
    }
    img.hoverborder:hover {
        border-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <p>Hover over the icon below:</p>
    <img class="hoverborder" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcW5L.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
function getBorder(obj, out){
    if(!out){
        obj.style.border = "blue solid 3px";
    }
    else {
        obj.style.border = "none";
    }
}

</script>

<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcW5L.png' onmouseover='getBorder(this);' 
                                      onmouseout='getBorder(this, true);'/>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/uEQqB/

**update**

without inline js, because of comments below:

```
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcW5L.png' id='hoverImg'/>
```

js:

```
var img = document.getElementById('hoverImg')
img.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {
    this.style.border = "blue solid 3px"
},false)
img.addEventListener('mouseout',function () {
    this.style.border = "none"
},false)
```

and here is the fiddle for above: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vy6QZ/

Comment: Downvoting because there is absolutely no need to do this with javascript. You can do it in CSS with a hover selector.

Comment: @Tom a hover selector wont work in **all** browsers unless its an anchor tag

Comment: Far too verbose for such a simple task.

Comment: whoa, seriously please explain better the `-1`'s a `:hover` selector does not work in all browsers...

Comment: That doesn't make this a good solution. Inline JS is a bad idea, and your code is especially baffling in its use of a function for onmouseover but raw code for onmouseout.

Comment: +1; unsure why the downvotes are coming when the OP specifically tagged with JavaScript.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll give you that. +1

Comment: @p.campbell, this is terrible coding practice, that's why the "haters" are downvoting.

Comment: @Naal: My understanding is that :hover works on non-a elements in [everything except IE6 and older](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover). It's still buggy in newer IE, but in lesser ways that aren't relevant here. That means it works in all browsers that matter.

Comment: @ceejay, you cant change that without adding events, i wanted to do it in the simplest way possible. that way the OP can use the same function for multiple imgs, but it can be changes out of  inline by just passing `document.getElementById('imgID')` into the `getBorder()` function

Comment: @Tom the OP would not have put `javascript` as a tag if the OP did not want to see a js solution...

Comment: @Neal: I think you're reading too much into that tag. I assume he tagged it javascript because he thought javascript might be useful, not because he required it. Tell you what, i'll comment on the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In the style section of your page or in the css file:

```
.square:hover
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: a hover selector wont work in all browsers unless its an anchor tag

Comment: @Neal it should not really matter that much if an IE6 user does not get a border on hover, it is just a visual thing. In IE7 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can do this using only CSS.

For anyone wanting a jQuery solution:

```
 <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#YourImg").mouseover(function () {
       $(this).css("border","3px solid #0000FF");  
    });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a JavaScript solution. The 'ZOMG CSS-only' downvoters are simply unaware of the OP's requirements.

Comment: There's no need to use javascript, since this can be done in CSS in such a way that it works on all non-obsolete browsers.

Comment: The OP *did not* ask for a javascript solution. He simply included the 'javascript' tag. It is perverse to suggest the use of javascript where it is not needed simply based on the presence of a tag.

Comment: @Tom: indeed; you must've read my answer. It can be done in CSS alone.  If there was The One True Way™ to style elements in an HTML document, there'd be only one answer to this question. OP tagged as JavaScript, (yes, I overstated; OP didn't *ask* for a JS solution) which means that JS is part of the question/answer in their mind. It's fine you didn't suggest a JS based answer. Does that mean that all JS is out of the qeustion? You seem to think so- "perverse". Why does `.css()` exist in the first place?

Comment: It's a matter of the right tool for the job. Javascript can do computation, which CSS can't; CSS is correspondingly simpler and faster. Javascript is the right tool for jobs where the right style can only be found by computation, and CSS is the right tool for jobs where the style can be found by the application of the kind of rules it provides. This job is of the latter kind.