# i want to draw image's border when i mouse over it (CSS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<img src="<?=$photo;?>" width="235" height="154" alt="<?=$name;?>" />
```

i want when the user mouse it over it draw a border of the image like facebook

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw small blue square when over my icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651767/draw-small-blue-square-when-over-my-icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for... http://jsfiddle.net/5mmhE/3/

Comment: Don't forget to add a border beforehand, as without it, the image bounces: http://jsfiddle.net/5mmhE/3/.

Comment: @Buffon... anytime. glad I could help!

Comment: @Buffon... I can't run IE6 on my Mac, what is the problem?

Comment: @Hristo : it works fine in FireFox & Opera But in IE6 it doesn't response when i mouse over it i tried that `img{
          h: expression(onmouseover=new Function("this.style.border='border: 1px solid #B3B3B3';"),
          onmouseout=new Function("this.style.border='1px solid transparent';"));
        }` in IE but useless

Comment: yeah... don't do that. Can you post like screenshots of what you see in IE6?

Comment: IE6 only supports `:hover` on `a` elements. Use [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html?sharedBy=Urlsave.net), or add the `border` to an `a` element, something like [http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5mmhE/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5mmhE/4/) should work in IE6.

Comment: Only i see is that there re border in the image whether i mouse over it or none

Answer (score 0):

CSS solution is to store link as a block and set it's background-image property in css and then add :hover to that link.